# How can I get an equivalent to sync_channel(0) in `tokio`?

Tags: rust, synchronization, rust-tokio, channel

I have a project that needs a lot of IO-bound threads (potentially hundreds) which makes the `tokio` runtime much more ideal than standard threads.

However, I also need rendezvous channels that block both the Sender and Receiver.

`std::sync::mpsc` has `sync_channel(0)`, but there's no equivalent in `tokio::sync::mpsc`. `channel(0)` will panic.

How can I combine these two things? Will standard channels still work?

Comment: Standard channels are not awaitablke, so they'll block the executor. As a workaround, you could wrap your channel operations in [`tokio::task::spawn_blocking`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.12.0/tokio/task/fn.spawn_blocking.html), i.e. replace `tx.send(message)` with `spawn_blocking(|| tx.send(message)).await`.

Comment: You can try [flume](https://docs.rs/flume/0.10.9/flume/), which claims to support rendezvous and async channels.

Comment: are you looking for [`Barrier`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.12.0/tokio/sync/struct.Barrier.html) ? Your question is unclear

Comment: @Stargateur The OP is looking for zero-capacity a.k.a. rendezvous channels. This mode of operation is supported by [stdlib](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/fn.sync_channel.html), [crossbeam](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.8.1/crossbeam/channel/fn.bounded.html), and [flume](https://docs.rs/flume/0.10.9/flume/fn.bounded.html), but not by tokio or async-std channels.

Comment: @user4815162342 so that what barrier is for

Comment: @Stargateur Barrier is when you need to wait for everyone to reach a common point. It requires you to know the number of peers, and it doesn't carry a payload. A rendezvous channel is just a bounded channel that performs no buffering whatsoever.

Comment: @user4815162342 that doesn't look like a good thing to do anyway

Comment: @Stargateur It's good when you need to send data between producers and consumers with zero bufferbloat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard library channels are not awaitable, so they'll block the executor. As a quick workaround, you could wrap your channel operations in [`tokio::task::spawn_blocking()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.12.0/tokio/task/fn.spawn_blocking.html), i.e. replace `tx.send(message)` with `spawn_blocking(|| tx.send(message)).await`.

A better option is to use a library that supports async rendezvous channels, such as [flume](https://docs.rs/flume/latest/flume/).